# How to make this Laplace function work? (Inverse Laplace transform)

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

In terms of force (F), acceleration (a), velocity (v), and position (y), with variables of impedance (R) and mass (m), I have a system where:

$y(t) = \frac{v(0) m}{2 R} (1-e^{\frac{-2 R t}{m}})$

$v(t) = v(0) e^\frac{-2 R t}{m}$

$f(t) = -2 R v(0) e^\frac{-2 R t}{m}$

I would like to derive the $y(t)$ equation from $F(t)$ using the Laplace domain as follows:

$F(s) = m A(s)$

$F(s) = m (s^{2} Y(s)- sy(0) - y'(0))$

$F(s) = m (s^{2} Y(s)- sy(0) - v(0))$, and if y(0) = 0, then:

$F(s) = m (s^{2} Y(s) - v(0))$

Rearranging, we get:

$Y(s) = \frac{F(s) + mv(0)}{ms^{2}}$

$Y(s) = \frac{F(s) + mv(0)}{m} * \frac{1}{s^{2}}$

But how do I now convert this back to the time domain and sub in $f(t)$? According to calculators and reference tables $\frac{1}{s^{2}} = t$, but if I just put $t$ in there for $\frac{1}{s^{2}}$ and change $F(s)$ to $f(t)$ it doesn't work.

So what is the correct operation to now do an inverse Laplace transform and get the $y(t)$ equation using $f(t)$?

Comment: The way you use the same letter $F$ for both time domain force and also for its $s$-domain transform is very confusing.

Comment: What should I do differently? That is how I have learned it. Eg. https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/Ideal_String_Struck_Mass.html

Comment: That page is consistent in using upper case for the Laplace transform, and lower for the original time-domain function, so $F(s)$ is the transform of $f(t)$, etc.  You do not, with $y$, at least.  It makes it hard to follow your calculations.

Comment: Okay thanks. I fixed that. I didn't realize that was the convention. Do you know how to do the inverse Laplace transform? I'm really stuck. This is for an audio synthesis project I am working on and I can't go any further without that solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your $Y(s)=v(0)/s^2 + F(s)/(ms^2)$, so you should get
$$
y(t) = v(0) t + \int_0^t (t-u) f(u) du /m$$
by using linearity of the LT to handle the sum of terms, pattern matching from the a table of LT pairs to handle $1/s^2$, and using the convolution formula for the product $F(s)/s^2$.